# how do i get input string from the frontend?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

```
public class Hello implements Function<APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent> {
    @Override
    public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent apply(APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent input) {
        APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent responseEvent = new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent();
        responseEvent.setStatusCode(200);
        responseEvent.setBody("Hello! Reached the Spring Cloud Function with message: " + input.getBody());
        return responseEvent;
    }
}
```

i have code like this teacher said i need to implements apply function. what i want to do is following. for example if i type some string in javascript submit button i want that string to go into my "APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent input" so i can return this string. if i am asking too ambiguous or big thing please tell me the key words that i need to study in order to do this

Comment: Are you saying you have a javascript client where you click a button and you want some text to be sent to API Gateway, which will invoke that java lambda function you have listed above?

Comment: yes that is what i was trying to say

Comment: Assuming your API Gateway and Lambda are already up and running, you need to make your client send a POST request to your API Gateway url. If your AWS side of things hasn't been done yet, then this is too much for one question.

Comment: i did the aws gateway endpoint url and its wokring fine. thanks for telling me what to do i will look for POST request thing.
i never actually have send POST request from real client. However i have tried with "Postman" app